# GoogleWebRTC on iOS (native) in combination with ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, arkit

I'm using Google's WebRTC Framework in combination with ARKit.

I installed WebRTC using this Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.3'

target 'myApp' do
  use_framework!

  pod "GoogleWebRTC"
end
```

I got audio working using this:

```
let audioDiscovery = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInMicrophone], mediaType: .audio, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
let audioDevice = audioDiscovery.devices[0]

let audioTrack = self.webRTCPeerConnectionFactory.audioTrack(withTrackId: audioDevice.uniqueID)
self.localMediaStream?.addAudioTrack(audioTrack)

self.webRTCPeerConnection?.add(self.localMediaStream!)
```

Then I tried the same for video (before adding the stream to the connection):

```
let videoDiscovery = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)
let videoDevice = videoDiscovery.devices[0]

let videoSource = self.webRTCPeerConnectionFactory.videoSource()
let videoTrack = self.webRTCPeerConnectionFactory.videoTrack(with: videoSource, trackId: videoDevice.uniqueID)
self.localMediaStream?.addVideoTrack(videoTrack)
```

But I can't see the video stream on the other side.

I solved the problem using a AVCaptureDevice with RTCVideoCapturer, but know ARKit doesn't show any video on the screen.